# splitting a proverb/refrain

Tags: sintaxis, proverbios

In English, we regularly split proverbs or refrains, at least in Ireland. What I mean by this is:

> Variety, as they say, is the spice of life.

Or

> A bird in the hand, it is often said is worth two in the bush.

And so on. So my question is: does this apply to Spanish? I know you can say:

> Como se dice **que** "la variedad es la sal de la vida"

but can you place "as they say/it is said" into the middle of the proverb?

> La variedad, como se dice, es la sal de la vida

It does not sound so natural to me in Spanish.

Secondly, is the use of **que** necessary in "como se dice **que** ..."?

Comment: Yes, and Spanish is, very often, much more flexible than English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can insert a comment clause.

The proverb is, for example:

- En la variedad está el gusto.

You can add a comment clause to make clear that it is not just your opinion but something everyone says and agrees with:

- Como dicen, en la variedad está el gusto.
- En la variedad, según dicen, está el gusto.

The comment clase may also be of use to indicate that you have a different opinion.

"Que" will only be used if you have a verb or a subject and a verb to introduce the saying (no "como" or "según"):

- Dicen **que** en la variedad está el gusto.
- La gente dice **que** en la variedad está el gusto.

Comment: Great! Sometimes, I think Spanish idiomatic phrases and expression  are like Irish ones, flexible and ,physical. One of the comments makes me wonder also. I notice "dicen que" and " como se dicen" and "según dicen".Again ,we use this a lot in Ireland but I suppose standard English would use the impersonal "it is said" or "one says". So, in formal essays is it better to say" se dice.." ?Clearly, "se dicen " can be used in conversation as we do.

Comment: Also, is the expression with "el gusto" used more?

Comment: In answer to your first question, please notice that the impersonal with "se" takes the singular "dice". "Dicen" has a tacit subject "ellos" (they). In formal Spanish, we would certainly use a passive or an impersonal form: Es sabido que ... / Se sabe que ...

Comment: In reply to your second question, I hear "en la variedad está el gusto" much more often than "la variedad es la sal de la vida".

Comment: great .that is fine